# Sagemaker AWS llama2 endpoint inference

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, large-language-model, llama

I am calling the inference endpoint of jumpstart-llama2-foundational-model on AWS sagemaker but it gives me the error below:

**Error raised by inference endpoint: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (424) from primary with message "{
"code":424,
"message":"prediction failure",
"error":"Allocation larger than expected: tag 'rms_qkv', requested size: 164831232, expected max size:  '100663296'"
}"**

My code snippet is as below:

```
llm = SagemakerEndpoint(
                        endpoint_name=endpoint_name, 
                        region_name=region, 
                        model_kwargs={"max_new_tokens": 2048, "top_p": 0.9, "temperature": 0.1},
                        endpoint_kwargs={"CustomAttributes": 'accept_eula=true'},
                        content_handler=content_handler
                )
prompt_template = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["chat_history", "human_input", "context"], template=Chat_llama().get_template())
                chain = load_qa_chain(llm, chain_type="stuff",memory=st.session_state['memory'], prompt=prompt_template)
            
chain({"input_documents": docs, "human_input": prompt}, return_only_outputs=True)
response=chain.memory.buffer
```

Could someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

from the error logs it seems like the input text is too large, can you try truncating it and see if you are running into the same error, so we can pinpoint the problem? Is there also anything you are doing in your custom inference script that's adding to the payload size?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are having the same problem as me (Are you also using a LLama2-13b endpoint in Sagemaker?). Basically, your input is too big for the model context window (1.64 bigger, to be more exact). If it's possible for you to reduce your input size to be under that max limit, that would be the best possible solution.

If that's not possible, than we are in the same situation. I have been looking around for solutions to possibly send the request in chunks/stream it to, somehow, work around that context window limitation.

Currently investigating if Langchain can help here somehow, will get back to this post if I find a solution.